# How to prevent user changing websocket ip

Tags: websocket

Some websites that use websockets can be manipulated into connecting to a specific ip by changing it in the console.

Is it possible to block this? So the user cannot choose a custom ip to connect to via the websocket?

For example, in the web browser game agar.io, how did they prevent the user choosing an ip in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Getter and Setter function for the variable, which contains the IP. The setter is like a function-less function and the getter returns the variable.

While initiating the script, you could use a different Setter function, which actually changes the value of the variable.

Comment: Couldn't the user still change the ip it connects to though?

Comment: If your protect the socket variable too, no.